How to implement curved shape at bottom center of a view in android using Path
I using below code to get a curved shape at the bottom center of a view.
class CustomCurvedView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = 0xFF4CAF50.toInt()
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    private val path = Path()
    private val cornerRadius = 50f
    private val curveHeight = 100f
    private val curveWidth = 200f

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val width = width.toFloat()
        val height = height.toFloat()

        val roundedRect = RectF(0f, 0f, width, height - curveHeight)

        path.reset()

        path.addRoundRect(roundedRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)

        path.moveTo(width / 2 - curveWidth / 2, height - curveHeight)

        val x1 = width / 2
        val y1 = height
        val x2 = width / 2 + curveWidth / 2
        val y2 = height - curveHeight

        path.cubicTo(
            width / 2 - curveWidth / 4, height,  // Control point 1
            width / 2 + curveWidth / 4, height,  // Control point 2
            x2, y2                               // End point
        )

        path.lineTo(width, height - curveHeight)

        path.lineTo(0f, height - curveHeight)

        path.close()

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }
}

I want to have a smoother corner near the curved shape. With above code it is coming sharp corner.
How can i archive smoother shape like attached.

I want to have result like image
I have tried the code attached and it show like below imageshould be smoother curve at the bottom
